# ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound error when using STI in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I am using Ruby on Rails 2.3.10. I have a class, `School`. I use STI to give me several subclasses: `PrimarySchool`, `SecondarySchool` and `University`.

```
app/models/primary_school.rb:
  class PrimarySchool < School
     has_many :education_records, :foreign_key => "school_id"
  end

app/models/secondary_school.rb:
  class SecondarySchool < School
     has_many :education_records, :foreign_key => "school_id"
  end

app/models/university.rb
  class University < School
     has_and_belongs_to_many :applicants, :join_table => :applicants_schools, :foreign_key => "school_id"
  end

db/migrate/20100824170203_create_schools.rb:
class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type     # secondary, cegep, college, university
      t.string :street
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :schools
  end
end
```

`PrimarySchool.first` and `PrimarySchool.last` work as expected. `SecondarySchool.first` and `SecondarySchool.last` work as expected. `University.last` works.

However, `University.first` and `University.all` raise a `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound` exception:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'University'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite University.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1671:in `instantiate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `collect!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:639:in `all'
    from (irb):6
    from :0
```

The SQL generated is correct:

```
  SecondarySchool Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE ( (`schools`.`type` = 'University' ) ) LIMIT 1
  SecondarySchool Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE ( (`schools`.`type` = 'University' ) ) ORDER BY schools.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2389) in the development mode.

One workaround is to register the subclasses at the bottom of the base class file.

```
%w(secondary_school university).each do |r| 
  require_dependency r
end if Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: class School < ActiveRecord::Base
end

%w(secondary_school university).each do |r| 
  require_dependency r
end if Rails.env.development?

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Also tried ./script/console production and still see the error.

Comment: This worked for me, though now I need to remember to restart rails server any time I change said sub-class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

KandadaBoggu put me on the right track. Pete P.'s workaround works for me:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.subclasses
    [PrimarySchool, SecondarySchool, OtherSchool, University]
  end
end
```

In that it gets rid of the exception...but it generates the wrong SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE ( (`schools`.`type` = 'University' OR
`schools`.`type` = 'PrimarySchool' OR `schools`.`type` = 'SecondarySchool' OR 
`schools`.`type` = 'OtherSchool' OR `schools`.`type` = 'PostSecondaryInstitution' OR 
`schools`.`type` = 'Cegep' OR `schools`.`type` = 'College' OR `schools`.`type` = 
'University' ) ) LIMIT 1
```

Renaming university.rb to uni.rb, changing the class name and UPDATEing the type column made this work. I'm really confused.